# How to compare 2 parameters in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 string parameters 1) filename 2) Path
filename - sample.txt
path - /usr/cole/jenkins/1240/hd/sample.txt

I want to compare if the "Path" has "Filename" in it and then perform some action if the condition is true

```
def matchpat = ('${params.path}' =~ /${params.filename}/)  
print matchpat
assert params.filename == matchpat[0]
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could use `String.endsWith(str)` method like:

```
def path = '/usr/cole/jenkins/1240/hd/sample.txt'
def filename = 'sample.txt'

if (path.endsWith(filename)) {
    println 'Performing some action...'
}
```

Running this script produces as expected:

```
Performing some action...
```

Comment: What if the text is in the middle and not at the end "like matching a dir name" ?